# With the new standalone feature in Angular, is there not a way to provide all CommonModule imports during bootstrap?

Tags: angular, angular-standalone-components

I've recently started having a play around with Angular's standalone feature and module-less approach. However, I'm struggling to find an answer/explanation to what I'm looking for.

As I understand it, with a standalone component you need to import any directives/pipes/components used within that component. If I have a basic component that uses *ngIf and *ngFor the decorator would look something like this:

```
@Component({
  imports: [NgIf, NgFor],
  selector: 'smd-dashboard',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="true">
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let letter of ['a', 'b', 'c']">{{ letter }}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `,
})
```

If using many common components/pipes/directives, previously you would import once within a module. Now you are saying we have to import NgIf etc in every single component, this becomes a little tedious and verbose surely in some scenarios?

For providers I can use [importProvidersFrom()](https://angular.io/api/core/importProvidersFrom) and do this at bootstrap to import many providers in one go, meaning I don't have to import `Router` every time I use it within the component. Why allow this for providers, but not have a similar feature for pipes?

**If the argument is that the component is standalone and its dependencies need to be injected, then why is it possible to use `provideRouter()` at bootstrap? Surely `RouterModule` should be imported into the standalone component too for use?

Is there an existing helper function similar to `importProvidersFrom()` that I am missing, that can be used for importing some frequently used components/directives/pipes in one go?**

Answer (score 1):

This is how standalone has been design : explicit dependencies. You import an component/directive you wish to use.

For `ngIf/ngFor/ngSwitch` the alternative is the use the new [built-in control flow](https://angular.dev/guide/templates/control-flow) which doesn't require any directive import.

Comment: or you can import the `CommonModule` that also includes among others: `ngClass`, `ngStyle`,`AsyncPipe`, `JsonPipe`,... see the [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/CommonModule)

Comment: That's useful to know regarding built-in control flow, I'll start experimenting with that next, thanks.

Regarding the point of explicit dependencies, surely the use of importProvidersFrom(), provideRouter(), provideHttpClient() etc during bootstrap goes against this principal as they enable a component to use providers such as HttpClient, Router etc without explicitly including them in the imports/providers?